# How to solve my computer boot issue (Monitor Switch automatically off)

Tags: boot, memory

When I start my computer, it boots well and runs for around 4 mins. After that the monitor automatically switching off and the Processor light on the CPU also got off. When i press restart button, still the CPU runs but the monitor not staring and also processor lights not getting on.

May I know whats the issue. I think its as hardware problem in CPU. I am sure monitor doesnt have problem. But eager to hear Expert's Comments. Thanks in advance

Comment: Set the monitor to manually switch off.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the processor's overheating. Reapply the thermal paste and check.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the cpu fan (Speed, cleaning from dust)